# How i can do simple counter?

Tags: python, function, counter

How can I make a "counter", and after this counter reaches for example 3, I had the function executed.
When I call the function "this", 3 and more times, "if this >= 3:" don't work, and I'm not understand why does this happen.

I already tried to write it, I asked more knowledgeable people, but I haven't found a solution.
Code which i write:

```
# question
def get_doing():
    return input('What u gonna do now, ' + name + '? ')


# doings
def doings():
    do = get_doing()
    this = 0
    if do == 'Anything':
        print('Good')

    else:
        print('Don\'t write, pls.')
        this += 1                                   # Here is a problem
    if this >= 3:
        print('If u keep it up, you\'re going to get in trouble.')


while True:
    doings()
```

Answer (score 0):

The counter needs to exist *outside* the function, so that its value is remembered between calls. For example,

```
def doings(c):
    do = get_doing()
    if do == "Anything":
        print("Good")
    else:
        print("Don't write, pls.")
        c += 1
    if c >= 3:
        print("If you keep it up, you're going to get in trouble")
    return c

c = 0
while True:
    c = doings(c)
```